# Get .js file value using Java

Tags: java

I have one config.js file:

```js
sOptions = {
  enabled: true,
  vtest: assign,
  stest: remove
}
```

I want to get value of 'vtest' using Java. I tried below code

```
ScriptEngine ee = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
ee.eval(new FileReader("config.js"));
System.out.println("ee: "+ee);
```

I am not seeing anything is write in log file.

Comment: What format is that file supposed to be in?

Comment: Using [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/nashorn/introduction.html#GUID-89EC58B9-A26D-45FD-84B1-AD7FEF1B2928), you could simply parse the JS file and run it. I guess using a regular expression is a faster option in your case.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I tried, please check my question

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need valid javascript. When I ran your original js I got exception messsages.

In the fix below I quoted both of your `'assign'` and `'remove'` values. Also, you need to print out the value that you want.

```java
import javax.script.*;

public class NashornTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String js = "sOptions = {\n" +
                    "  enabled: true,\n" +
                    "  vtest: 'assign',\n" +
                    "  stest: 'remove'\n" +
                    "}";
        ScriptEngine ee = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        ee.eval(js);
        
        System.out.println("ee:" + ee);
        System.out.println("sOptions: "+ee.get("sOptions"));
    }

}
```

Which shows.

> ee:jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine@b3ca52e
> sOptions: [object Object]

The next step is to get what you want from the data. Also, if you're just using JSON, you might want to use a JSON library instead of javascript.